# Spring does not accept an abstract class inheritor as an argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have the following problem while creating a model in Spring Boot.

Created an abstract model class -

```
public abstract class AbstractRequest {
    private String tariffType;
}
```

And his heir

```
public class Request extends AbstractRequest {
   // some fields
}
```

In the controller I pass an abstract request

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<PriceResponse> calculate(@RequestBody AbstractRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(calculationService.calculate(request));
}
```

The service interface also has an abstract request class

```
public interface CalculationService {
    PriceResponse calculate(AbstractRequest request);
}
```

In the implementation of the service interface, I am trying to accept the successor of the abstract model

```
@Service
public class CalculationServiceFTL implements CalculationService {
    @Override
    public PriceResponse calculate(Request request) {
    }
}
```

And as a result I get an error

```
Class 'CalculationServiceFTL' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'calculate(AbstractRequest)' in 'CalculationService'
```

Please explain why spring does not accept an abstract class heir as an argument and how should I be in this case if I can have several abstract model heirs and I need to process them differently in different services. Thanks

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring.. Java doesn't work like that. You should be implementing the method and not change it. Your `CalculationServiceFTL` doesn't implement the `calculate` method. with the `AbstractRequest` method (and no `calculate(Request request)` isn't that method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An abstract class cannot be instantiated directly but by its inheriting concrete classes.
2. Any concrete class inheriting the abstract class should be instantiable with a constructor (if not abstract itself of course). But use of a constructor is prohibited by Spring because any class that we instantiate this way cannot be taken in charge by Spring’s automated dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What can I do in this case to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: you have do the same as above answer

Comment: ```@Service
public class CalculationServiceFTL implements CalculationService {
    @Override
    public PriceResponse calculate(AbstractRequest request) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing an interface you need to implement all the unimplemented methods from the interface you're implementing with the same method signature .

```
public interface CalculationService {
    PriceResponse calculate(AbstractRequest request);
}
```

so your implemented class should also have same implemented method with same signature like

```
@Service
public class CalculationServiceFTL implements CalculationService {
    @Override
    public PriceResponse calculate(AbstractRequest request) {
    }
}
```

So in order to resolve this you can change the parameter type in interface class or your implemented service class so that those are same.